# Cannot authenticate my MongoDB database despite setting proper credentials

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have a MongoDB database running under Docker, and am attempting to access it through a Spring Boot reactive repository. My
docker-compose.yml file is below:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongotest:
    image: mongo:4.4.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ~/software/mongobase/mongodata:/data/db
      - ~/software/mongobase/logs:/root/logs
      - ~/software/mongobase/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <redacted>
      MONGO_INIDB_DATABASE: testdatabase
```

I am loading MongoDB support for Spring Boot using the following maven dependences:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My application.properties file is below:

```
server.port=8080

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:<redacted>@myhost:27017/testdatabase
```

Despite the fact that the username and password used in my application.properties file are the same as the username and password
set in the my docker file, I am getting the following exception whenever I attempt to access the database:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdatabase', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdatabase', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdatabase', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdatabase', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:2954) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
                    .
                    .
                    .
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdatabase', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:276) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server myhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:512) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Looking at the MongoDB log, I am seeing that the authentication failures are caused by MongoDB "not finding" the username root! But
didn't I set the username root in my docker-compose.yml file???

I must be missing something here. Could someone tell me what I am missing?

How do I make my MongoDB database accept proper credentials?

Comment: Specify the authentication database when connecting. Use **admin**.

Answer (score 0):

I think INITDB password and the database password need to be separate, you can try it out with this:

```
environment:
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
  - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=$MONGO_DB
  - MONGO_DB_USERNAME=$MONGO_DB_USERNAME
  - MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I did try separating the username and password as you suggested. The MongoDB logs do not show the creation of a username, and the username is still "not found".